# Generate random values based on a variable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to generate a random number based on accuracy of a player. If his accuracy is more, his cost should be more.

For ex,

```
      if accuracy >= 0.9, cost = 0.7

      else if accuracy >= 0.8, cost = 0.6
      (something like this)
```

cost is a random floating point number between 0 and user_specified_value. If his accuracy is closer to 1, I want cost to be generated closer to user_specified_value.

How do I generate the cost based on the accuracy?

Thank you.

Comment: Aside from syntax, what's wrong with what you have done? And you haven't shown any random number generation here. Also, what does `closer` mean in this context?

Comment: The idea is to simulate real world scenario. Say for example, in an auction a player's cost depends on his skill level. Buying Messi would cost more than buying Torres. So how would you do this in a simulator if you only know what is the highest value you can spend on a player (user_specified_value). If user says 2 billion, For Messi, I need to generate probably 1.8 billion, but for Torres I can generate 1.5 billion.

Comment: The issue is I have to generate both skill and cost randomly. I cannot do that separately bcoz they are dependent on each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you're asking about is sampling from a distribution.

Python's [random](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module provides several distributions, the choice of which depends on what you want for your application. For example random.random() returns floating points uniformly distributed between 0.0 and 1.0.

### Uniform

You might want to sample costs uniformly from a band that gets higher with accuracy, like this:

```
cost = (random.random() * spread + min(accuracy, (1-spread))) * user_specified_value
```

Spread defines how wide the band is, and we draw uniformly within the band, sliding the band upward as accuracy increases stopping when we bump up against 100%.

Let's see how this looks, generating 1000 random samples:

The y axis here is cost. The x axis is just the order in which the samples were drawn and is meaningless. Here's what you get for low accuracy (0.01)
[image: accuracy=0.01]

Dialing the accuracy up to 0.30, get's you random costs in this range:
[image: accuracy=0.30]

And for highly accurate players (0.99), we get:
[image: accuracy=0.99]

### Triangular distribution

Another way to scale up the costs would be to use a [triangular distribution](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.triangular), something like this:

```
cost = random.triangular(0.0,max(0.01,accuracy),1.0)
```

This time, the x axis is accuracy, the cost, y, scales up gradually. Note that a highly accurate player can still get a low cost, but a low accuracy player never gets a high cost:
[image: triangular distribution]

BTW, I used the plotting library [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) and the following code to generate these nifty plots.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

user_specified_value = 100.0
spread = 0.33
n = 1000

## uniform
accuracy = 0.01
costs = [0] * n
for i in range(0,n):
    costs[i] = random.random() * user_specified_value * accuracy
plt.scatter(range(0,n), costs)
plt.ylim(0, 100)

## triangular
accuracy = [0] * n
costs = [0] * n
for i in range(0,n):
    accuracy[i] = float(i)/n
    costs[i] = random.triangular(0.0,max(0.01,accuracy[i]),1.0) * user_specified_value
plt.scatter(accuracy, costs)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was asking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
from __future__ import division ## this lets us do non integer division
import random

user_specified_value = 5

if accuracy >= 0.9:
    cost = random.randrange(user_specified_value//2,user_specified_value,1)/10
else:
    cost = random.randrange(0,user_specified_value,1)/10
```

Because we imported `__future__` all division using `/` will be floating point division.  If you want integer division just use `//`.  Float division is the default in python 3.

`random.randrange` doesn't like non-integers, so if you want a decimal cost you have to specify `user_specified_value` as an integer.